# How to ensure multiple outputs of a regression model sum up to a specific number like 1 or 100?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

My each training point is a group of people and I have to predict what fraction of people will go to each of the 4 classes they can go to. For example, a training point would have 100 people in it and my model's job would be to predict, e.g., 10% people will got to class A, 30% to class B, 15% to class C and 45% to class D. If I use regression (of any form, not only linear). Also, how do i ensure that all the predicted fractions sum up to 1 or 100%?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean logistic regression?  In any case each sample will end up with a predicted class, so the total will have to equal 100% of the training samples.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: @Chris: I am talking about any algorithm that does regression (predicts continuous output) that will include neural networks, boosted trees, SVR, and so on.

Comment: @desertnaut: it is a data science question and I cannot figure out anywhere that one cannot ask data science questions. Plus, if there is a way to do it, it will be absolutely related to programming because essentially I am seeking ways to implement the relevant constraint in my ML algorithm.

Comment: Data science = programming + other stuff. SO is about the *programming* part; questions about the other stuff (theory, methodology, terminology, guidelines etc) are off-topic here - we have a dedicated [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this. The fact that you cannot figure that anywhere may simply mean that you have not actually looked hard enough; for starters, please see the intro and **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: The Meta threads [Do pure “machine learning” questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow), [Guidance for asking machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/guidance-for-asking-machine-learning-questions), and [Standard for machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/standard-for-machine-learning-questions) are also relevant. You are welcome.